# Encryption/Decryption engine

Tags: linux, assembly

I started to program a simple encryption/decryption engine as a kick-start for a bigger project for my school. I use assembly to program it and the logic until now is the following: i do some parsing for the arguments in the command line to take the input filename and output filename, then i read the input file into an inner buffer, i produce a pseudo-random byte to encrypt the buffer, and then i will try to add as a stub in the beginning of the buffer the decrypt routine and then save the new buffer into the output file that will be created. Is this the right way to do it? I'm asking because i have my doubts when i read the input file into the buffer. I think i read the whole file, while i should read only its code part? I'm not sure any suggestions/corrections are welcome. I'm using a 32-bit linux and assembly.

Comment: are you willing to call this function after reading the file?

Comment: i read the file that is going to be encrypted first, then i encrypt the buffer that contains the data read from the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> add the decrypt routine and then save the new buffer into the output file

Probably you are doing it wrong. If you wanna alter code size you have to do it with ELF program/section tables too. You can write a program which will read ELF header and add $DECRYPTION_ROUTINE_SIZE to size of .text section, do some copy etc.
Hope it can be useful: http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

You can append your decryption routine to .text of file, alter header and insert

```
jmp    original_entry_point
```

Comment: it will probably be data file, not executable

Comment: >I think i read the whole file, while i should read only its code part?

Comment: I am directed to this approach you suggested before i read your answer, it seems most logical. So you say to read the header file from elf, and to write the decryption routine inside the text section after i encrypt the original text section? Also is there always space to write the decryption routine inside?

Comment: If there is no space left, you always can modify header to make it bigger. And then shift code to the end by several bytes, which will contain decryption routine. Or try my suggestion: change entrypoint to your decryption procedure and in the end of it do a jump to original entrypoint. In this case decryption routine should be in the beginning of code or in the end.

Comment: why are you encrypting it anyway? if decryption routine will be inside the file, then what's the point?

Comment: @fazo is that what an encryption/decryption engine does? i mean you are right, but i have a project to make a simple polymorphic engine to graduate(!) and i started to do some simple things in order to understand what i have to do. Please feel free to enlight me, if i'm completely off of the subject!